# ThreadAbortException

Tags: vb.net

this is my button click sub

```
Protected Sub abc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsavecurrent.Click
    Try
        If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
        Saveabc()
        Response.Redirect("abc.aspx")
    Catch exab As Threading.ThreadAbortException
    Catch ex As Exception
        ReportError(ex, Session, Request)
    End Try
End Sub
```

after going to response.redirect, it moves to next line of ThreadAbortException and doesnt goto the abc.aspx. it just says session expired. how do i make it goto the abc.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Its the way Response.Redirect is implemented, Response.End generates a ThreadAbortException for notifying the processing engine.

This [article](http://www.c6software.com/articles/ThreadAbortException.aspx) has a work around for solving this. In general you probably don't want to catch ThreadAbortException if you are doing a Redirect.

I believe this is also documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332828%28VS.71%29.aspx) as well.